# How to have multiple entries for custom entity?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

In our Dynamics CRM online custom project - we've the default **ACTIVITIES** tab in a custom entity named `DocProject`'s form

[image: Activities inside custom entity's Form]

**ACTIVITIES** is able to take ***multiple entries***.

Also, there is **NOTES** tab in the same form

[image: Notes inside custom entity's Form]

**NOTES** is also able to take ***multiple entries***.

Okey, this is done by Dynamics CRM guys. So far so good.

In the same form, we also have a `DocProjectActivities` [lookup field](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VwF9O2AOmEw) for a custom entity `DocProjectActivities`

[image: custom entity DocProjectActivities]

This is a lookup field, [hence it has got a 1:N relationship](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn531171.aspx).

> Clarification: Our problem is not only about **Activities**. WKT **Notes** also behaves similarly. We just need some `config` which will allow us to make multiple entries for one single field

## Problem:

> How do one makes sure that this custom entity `DocProjectActivities` allows to make multiple entries as that for **ACTIVITIES** & **NOTES**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you need multiple docprojectactivities on the form where you have the activities?
You need to create a 1:n relationship between the form and the docprojectactivities and add the subgrid on that form allowing you to create multiple records for the `docprojectactivities`.
A lookup field is the '1' side of the 1:n relationship and thus the wrong direction.

Go to `docprojectactivities`, add a new field type relationship towards the entity you are working on.
Save and publish.

Now go back to the form designer of the entity you need the entries on and go to the tab 'insert'.

Click on sub-grid and select only related records `docprojectactivities` (entity you are working on)

Answer (score 2):

In order to have the associated activity grid like the one in the DocProject entity, you need to enable the option **Activities** when you're creating the entity (this option can't be changed after the entity is created). This option will create the association with the activities entities and allow you to track all the related phone calls, task, etc.

[image]

I think that the problem that you're having is that you defined the DocProjectActivities as an activity entity and therefore you can't have this kind of relationship with the other activities entities. I recommend you to take a look to the differences between [Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309396.aspx) and [Activity Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309626.aspx).

Comment: Our problem is not only about **Activities**. WKT **Notes** also behaves similarly. We just need some `config` which will allow us to make multiple entries for one single field

Comment: In the screenshot you will be able to see that the relationship between a custom entity and Notes is configured in the same way that the Activities one. It's also important to remark that this option can not be changed after the entity is created so there's no config available to generate it after the entity is created, you will need to create again the entity.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your custom entity to work as an [activity entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309626.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), you should have selected "Define as an activity entity" when you created it.

You cannot make a normal lookup field to multiple entities (with the exception being the possibility of creating Customer fields that was introduced in 2016.1).

Comment: I just wanted to have multiple entries allowed for my custom entity,  will it allow me to achieve this?

Comment: You want a subgrid?