# Show entity form fields on the main SubGrid

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

We've got an entity `DocProjectActivity` which is presented inside a [SubGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155346/how-to-have-multiple-entries-for-custom-entity#comment67579930_40155602).

[image: entity subgrid]

The entity has got a set of form fields:

- **Priotity**
- **Owner**
- etcetera...

[image: entity details]

## Challenge:

> Show form fields **Priotity**, **Owner** on the main `SubGrid`

[image: Show form fields on the main SubGrid]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the columns to the *Active DocProjectActivities* view, which is the view shown in the subgrid.

Comment: how do you access this **View thing**

Comment: You can access/customize this "view thing" by going to customization->default solution->your entity->views.