# Update Business Process Flow specific details in Dynamics CRM project

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

In the Dynamics CRM 365, we've customized the **Business Process Flow** specific to the needs:

[image: Business process flow]

As shown in the screenshot, the **Source** stage is nesting 2 fields:

> Subject
>
> Description

We wanted to customize these.

- Maybe by adding fields?
- Specifically we wish to add [SubGrids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155346/how-to-have-multiple-entries-for-custom-entity#comment67609277_40155602).

From where we can update these Stage specific details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stages cannot contain Subgrids, you can put fields (making them mandatory or not according to your needs).

Business Process Flows being Processes, they can be edited either from SETTINGS -> PROCESSES or through solutions (which have a 'Processes' element).

[Finally, as always when it comes to customizing, docs are on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481586.aspx)

Comment: Okey, so how do we add fields there?

Comment: Expanded the answer with more info, see the MSDN link to learn how to customize the flows (it's a **long** explanation which doesn't belong on SO)

Comment: Thank you @Alex for investing your precious time! I'll have a look into it and get back